# Tooltip of angularjs material shows different position with right and left direction

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Im using AngularJs Material's tooltip and i run into a weird behaviour - when i set the direction to right - then it's shows the tooltip with different spacing then with left direction

Right :
[image]

Left:
[image]

As you can see - the right direction got more margin then the left one....
I wonder how can i set them to equal spacing (i prefer the right margin...)

I've tried to add the tooltip before and after the icon - just for the sake of testing - but it didn't worked.

```
 <md-button class="md-fab">
         <md-tooltip ng-show="isRTL" md-direction="{{demo.tipDirection}}">
          Insert Drive
        </md-tooltip>
        <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_insert_drive_file_24px.svg">
          <md-tooltip ng-show="!isRTL" md-direction="{{demo.tipDirection}}">
          Insert Drive
        </md-tooltip>
        </md-icon>
  </md-button>
```

B.t.w - the same bug appear on Angular Material tooltip [example](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tooltip)

Here is an [Example](https://codepen.io/royBarak80/pen/jOVmOEL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the tooltip css.

Try this:

```
.md-tooltip.md-origin-left {
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}
```